# Spring @Qualifier strange behaviour with setter injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I run into a code that has some strange `@Qualifier` behavior. It is not what I would expect.

Let's consider the following code snippet:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Foo foo1() {
        return new Foo("foo1");
    }

    @Bean
    Foo foo2() {
        return new Foo("foo2");
    }

    static class Foo {
        private final String name;

        public Foo(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    @Component
    static class Bar {
        private Foo fooOne;
        private Foo fooTwo;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("foo3")
        void setFoo(Foo foo1, Foo foo2) {
            this.fooOne = foo1;
            this.fooTwo = foo2;
        }

        @PostConstruct
        void printFoo() {
            System.out.println(fooOne.getName() + fooTwo.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't work because there is no `Foo` bean named `foo3`. This is exactly what I expect. Now let's change `Foo` class definition to include a `@Qualifier`:

```java
    @Qualifier("foo3")
    static class Foo {
    // remaining code not changed..
```

With that change, the `@Qualifier` on `Bar::setFoo` method seems to be ignored and instances `foo1` and `foo2` are injected. No bean with id `foo3` is present in the context. I have hard time understanding the mechanism applied here. Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 1):

By putting the qualifier on class Foo:

```java
    @Qualifier("foo3")
    static class Foo {
        ...
    }
```

Every bean instantiated as a class `Foo` will have the given qualifier. You are correct that are is not a single bean with *id* `foo3`, however there are two beans present with a *qualifier* `foo3`.

More information on the topic can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025075/how-do-you-inject-a-list-of-beans-with-the-same-qualifier).

To inject both beans, remove the qualifier on the static class and add a qualifier on both parameters:

```java
  @Autowired
  void setFoo(@Qualifier("foo1") Foo foo1, @Qualifier("foo2") Foo foo2) {
```

To play around with beans in an application context, I'd suggest injecting the application context and retrieving the beans to inspect them. For instance:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
      
       // Beans by qualifier
       BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(context.getBeanFactory(), YourClass.class, "foo3");
    }

... 
}
```